# Jquery Get textbox value

Tags: jquery

How to get the textbox value of all fields when a key is entered. Im able to get only first and last textbox value. I failed to get the middle textbox value.

```
        $("#GridView1 :text").live("keyup", recalculate);

function recalculate() {
                 $("#GridView1 tbody tr:first").each(function () {
                     var text = $(":text", this);
                     var First = Number.parseInvariant(text.first().val());
                     var Middle= Number.parseInvariant(text.first().next().val());
                     var Last= Number.parseInvariant(text.last().val());
                });
            }
```

Comment: instead of tr:first each , try :text each

Comment: Hello @Kurt 666, I have added snippet below, you can refer that,in case of still required anything else please let me know. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a sample example using the table with text boxes, so you can refer that snippet, might be it helps you.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  recalculate();
});

function recalculate() {
  $("#GridView1").find("tr").each(function(e, element) {
    var firstTextBox = $($(element).find('input[type="text"]')[0]).val();
    var secondTextBox = $($(element).find('input[type="text"]')[1]).val();
    var thirdTextBox = $($(element).find('input[type="text"]')[2]).val();
    console.log("Grid Row : " + (e + 1) + " txt1: " + firstTextBox + " txt2: " + secondTextBox + " txt3: " + thirdTextBox);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="GridView1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(i){
    console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

you will get all text box values.